# Wordpress Import CSV data into MySQL table truncates some fields

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using the built-in Import in the Wordpress dashboard to get CSV data from a file created by Excel into a table. It creates a new table and enters data as expected, but on one field which it automatically defined as varchar(8) should really be varchar(10) so some characters are dropped. I can't find settings that may fix the problem and even if I create a new table correctly, I can't see how I can force the import into that new table. Any advice would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, I've had the problem where the importer assumed the length of the column based on the first 1000 rows or so, you may be able to fix it by creating a new row at the top with 10 characters in that column.

Comment: *It creates a new table and enters data* This is not correct. You must create a table with correct columns definitions then import the data into this existing table. Your tool must provide such option. PS. It makes no sense to create short VARCHAR column in most cases - this does not save disk space until VARCHAR(255).

Comment: Thanks for advice but adding a line at the start didn't work. Problem now solved by letting the import create the table incorrectly as stated, then alter table as required, truncate and re-import. I noted in that the SQL the import produces only creates a new table if it doesn't exist! All I had to do then was to rename the table it produced.